# Make brand name linkable under product title in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to place a clickable link for brands under the product title on Woocommerce single product pages.

I have successfully been able to put the brand under the title, but can't make it a link to the brand category page.

Any help?

I'm using the WooCommerce Brands plugin.

And here is the code I'm using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_brands_add_brand_name', 8 );

function wc_brands_add_brand_name() {
    global $product;
    $brands =  implode(', ', wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_brand', ['fields' => 'names']));
    echo "<p>Brand: " . '<a href="' . 'need hyperlink here' . '">' . $brands . '</a>' . "</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_the_term_list](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/) is the right function to use in a situation where you want to show links of terms of a post.

In `get_the_term_list` you can set before, after & separator, so you don't even have to make an `if` check for show/hide the string.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Display product brands
 */
function vh_wc_display_brand_links() {
    global $product;

    echo get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), 'product_brand', '<p class="product-brands">' . __( 'Brands:', 'text-domain' ) . ' ', ', ', '</p>' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'vh_wc_display_brand_links', 8 );
```

Comment: Wow! That worked perfectly.  Thank you so much, Vijay, for taking the time.